# When did Gwenpool meet Ms. Marvel?

Tags: marvel, comics, ms-marvel, gwenpool

In Champions Vol 2 #5, Gwenpool tells the Champions that she's met Ms. Marvel before. I want to see this meeting for myself, but I don’t know what comic it happened in.

When did Gwenpool meet Ms. Marvel?

Comment: When did modern comics stop putting in the little footnotes, referencing which issue of which publication the mentioned event is from? `* Last ish. -stan the man`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They met in [Gwenpool Special Vol 1. #1 (2015)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Gwenpool_Special_Vol_1_1) at She-Hulk's xmas office party.

[image]